# Elliptic points of modular group

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modular-forms

For $SL_2(Z)$ we know the elliptic point is either equivalent to $i$ or $1/2+\sqrt{3}/2i$.

Then for finite index subgroup of $SL_2(Z)$, $\Gamma$, is this still true? There will be fewer points fixed by elliptic element of $\Gamma$, but also fewer equivalent classes, so I am not sure.

Comment: Some subgroups have more elliptic fixed points, and some have fewer. There are explicit formulas for the number of inequivalent elliptic points of the groups $\Gamma(N),\Gamma_0(N)$, and $\Gamma_1(N)$, see for instance Miyake's book on modular forms.

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks! I have found the formula, which really surprises me. If it may have many equivalent classes, is it possible that all the elliptic points lie in either $Q(I)$ or $Q(\sqrt{3})$. This is clearly true for $\Gamma $ is $SL_2(Z)$, do you know whether this is true for other modular group? Thanks!

Comment: It's true for at least for any $\Gamma$ which consists only of matrices with rational entries. After all, an elliptic element has finite order, so its eigenvalues (over $\mathbb{C}$) are roots of unity. On the other hand, they satisfy a quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ since the matrix is $2\times 2$, so that just leaves $i,\rho,$ and $-\bar{\rho}$.

Comment: @carmichael561 I am sorry, so they satisfy which polynomial so that the solution is in $Q(I)$ or $Q(\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of the matrix.

Comment: @carmichael561 Thank you very much! I finally realized the fixed point is actually the first component of the eigenvector.